# Loop Syntax Issues

Tags: vba, excel, loops, syntax

I am coding a series of loops to search one table row by row for data, and if it meets the correct specs within that row it will pull a certain value from said row and place it in a cell I want in a separate table on another chart. I am getting the error saying that there is a "Next" without a "For", but there is (unless I am entirely missing something). It also has the Sub line at the top highlighted (I am trying to run this as a macro). Let me know where I am going wrong here, thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub GraphLoop()

Dim i, g, row, color, roundcount, round, materialcount, material As Long
Dim chartdatacol, chartdatarow As Long




Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("C6:DR10000").Value = ""

        roundcount = 1
        materialcount = 1
        color = 1
        round = 1
        material = 1
        chartdatacol = 3
        chartdatarow = 6
        i = 4

For chartdatacol = 3 To Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(4, cols.Count).End(xlUp).row

Do Until i = Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row


        g = 1



        If Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(chartdatarow, 2).Value _
            And Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 2).Value = round _
            And Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 3).Value = color _
            And Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 4).Value = material Then

            row = chartdatarow

            Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(row, chartdatacol).Value = _
            Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 6 + Worksheets("Analysis").Range("C5").Value).Value


            chartdatarow = chartdatarow + 1
            i = 4


        Else

            i = i + 1


        End If



Loop


    color = color + 1

    ' loops through ten colors
        If color > 10 Then

            color = 1

        End If

    roundcount = roundcount + 1
    materialcount = materialcount + 1

    ' every ten columns, material changes, every 30 columns, it repeats
        If materialcount = 11 Or 21 Then

            material = material + 1

        End If

        If materialcount > 30 Then

            materialcount = 1
            material = 1

    ' each round's 30 combos is 30 columns
        If roundcount = 31 Then

            round = round + 1

        End If


Next chartdatacol




End Sub
```

Comment: Is that second `Dim` on its own line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out an End If here:

```
If materialcount > 30 Then

        materialcount = 1
        material = 1

' each round's 30 combos is 30 columns
```

BTW, another correction to make:

```
    If materialcount = 11 Or 21 Then
```

should be:

```
    If materialcount = 11 Or materialcount = 21 Then
```

Comment: Thanks! Looked right past it. Also, now I am getting an error with the "For chartdatacol = 3 ..." line. I thought this would run until it hits the first empty cell, or the end of my chart. If you have a second, is there anything noticeably wrong with this?

Comment: I assume you meant to use this: For chartdatacol = 3 To Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column      but I may be wrong. You cols.Count is definitely not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You had an `If` without `End If`

See modified code below , I marked with ********* the place you were missing the End If :

```
Option Explicit
Dim i, g, row, color, roundcount, round, materialcount, material    As Long
Dim chartdatacol, chartdatarow                                      As Long


Sub GraphLoop()


Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("C6:DR10000").Value = ""

    roundcount = 1
    materialcount = 1
    color = 1
    round = 1
    material = 1
    chartdatacol = 3
    chartdatarow = 6
    i = 4

    For chartdatacol = 3 To Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).row

        Do Until i = Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            g = 1
            If Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(chartdatarow, 2).Value _
                And Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 2).Value = round _
                And Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 3).Value = color _
                And Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 4).Value = material Then

                row = chartdatarow

                Worksheets("Chart Data").Cells(row, chartdatacol).Value = _
                Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Cells(i, 6 + Worksheets("Analysis").Range("C5").Value).Value
                chartdatarow = chartdatarow + 1
                i = 4
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop

        color = color + 1

        ' loops through ten colors
        If color > 10 Then
            color = 1
        End If

        roundcount = roundcount + 1
        materialcount = materialcount + 1

        ' every ten columns, material changes, every 30 columns, it repeats
        If materialcount = 11 Or 21 Then
            material = material + 1
        End If

        If materialcount > 30 Then
            materialcount = 1
            material = 1
            ' each round's 30 combos is 30 columns
            If roundcount = 31 Then
                round = round + 1
            ' **** YOU WERE MISSING the End If here ***
            End If
        End If
    Next chartdatacol

End Sub
```